# How to know which network driver .inf file to deploy to client PC?

Tags: windows-server-2012, drivers, wds

I have a client with an ASUS Gryphon Z97 motherboard. It is unable to boot via WDS and if I install the OS manually then the standard Windows 7 install has no drivers for it's Ethernet Controller. I've looked up the `Hardware ID` and it is `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_15A1&SUBSYS_85C41043&REV_00`. I've also downloaded the LANdriver package found on ASUS's support website. This is all fine but in WDS when adding drivers it asks you to select the inf file corresponding to the driver you wish to install. These have such helpful names as `e1d64x64.inf`, `e1r64x64.inf`, `v1q64x64.inf`. My question is, how am I supposed to know which of these I should be deploying to my client without necessarily 'cluttering' up the client. Or should I just select them all and it won't really cause any performance impact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well adding them to WDS  certainly isn't going to hurt anything, but you should be able to reference that hardware ID within the .inf if you really want to limit the drivers that you have sitting out on WDS.

For the intel 1218v it would be dev_15a1 which is found in the e1d64x64.inf file in the prowinx64.exe package

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23071&lang=eng&ProdId=3707

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. You can also install the driver package manually then look at which inf was referenced by going to `Device Manager -> Your Device -> Driver Details -> Files` Thanks for this!